# Does boost::interprocess::named_mutex need to be stored in shared memory?

Tags: c++, synchronization, boost-interprocess

I want to use `boost::interprocess` to perform synchronization across multiple processes; in the specific I want to to use `boost::interprocessnamed_mutex` under Linux OS ( I am using g++ ) .

Do you know if each instance of this class has to be stored in shared memory like the simple `boost::interprocess::mutex`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do you know if each instance of this class has to be stored in shared memory like the simple boost::interprocess::mutex?

The "named" objects don't have to be in the shared memory. See this [example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/interprocess/synchronization_mechanisms.html#interprocess.synchronization_mechanisms.mutexes.mutexes_named_example) in the Boost.Interprocess documentation.

Comment: Thanks Simon! Side question ( if you have time ) Basically if I want to have multiple instances of a named_mutex I need to provide different names, right? If multiple named_mutex WITHING the same process use the same name, then they are referring to the same object and they will be synchronized...am I correct?  
NOTE: My question arose right because I saw that example while in the example for 'unnamed mutex' instances were accessible from shared memory.

Comment: Yes, if different named mutexes are used you have to name it different. Named mutexs are not only withing the same process but also within different processes of the OS the same!